# findLibrary returned null

Tags: java, android

working on a android app and when I click my button it should  take me to NDKmolActivity well when I test the app out and i click the button I the app crashes please help

```
            EDIT I FOUND THE LIBS!!! :) NEW ERROR :(
```

Logcat:

> 08-09 00:15:09.762: D/dalvikvm(15550): Trying to load lib
>   /data/app-lib/com.d4a.sts-1/libNdkmol.so 0x4239a320 08-09
>   00:15:09.762: D/dalvikvm(15550): Added shared lib
>   /data/app-lib/com.d4a.sts-1/libNdkmol.so 0x4239a320 08-09
>   00:15:09.762: D/dalvikvm(15550): No JNI_OnLoad found in
>   /data/app-lib/com.d4a.sts-1/libNdkmol.so 0x4239a320, skipping init
>   08-09 00:15:09.772: D/ESmol(15550): Data dir is
>   /storage/emulated/0/PDB 08-09 00:15:09.772: D/NDKmol(15550):
>   Initializing sample data /storage/emulated/0/PDB/2POR.pdb 08-09
>   00:15:09.772: W/dalvikvm(15550): No implementation found for native
>   Lcom/d4a/sts/NdkView;.nativeAdjustZoom:(I)[F 08-09 00:15:09.772:
>   D/AndroidRuntime(15550): Shutting down VM 08-09 00:15:09.772:
>   W/dalvikvm(15550): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception
>   (group=0x41af4700) 08-09 00:15:09.782: E/AndroidRuntime(15550): FATAL
>   EXCEPTION: main 08-09 00:15:09.782: E/AndroidRuntime(15550):
>   java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native method not found:
>   com.d4a.sts.NdkView.nativeAdjustZoom:(I)[F 08-09 00:15:09.782:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(15550):  at
>   com.d4a.sts.NdkView.nativeAdjustZoom(Native Method) 08-09
>   00:15:09.782: E/AndroidRuntime(15550):    at
>   com.d4a.sts.NdkView.resetCamera(NdkView.java:62) 08-09 00:15:09.782:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(15550):  at
>   com.d4a.sts.NdkView.(NdkView.java:58) 08-09 00:15:09.782:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(15550):  at
>   com.d4a.sts.NDKmolActivity.onCreate(NDKmolActivity.java:110) 08-09
>   00:15:09.782: E/AndroidRuntime(15550):    at
>   android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133) 08-09
>   00:15:09.782: E/AndroidRuntime(15550):    at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
>   08-09 00:15:09.782: E/AndroidRuntime(15550):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
>   08-09 00:15:09.782: E/AndroidRuntime(15550):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
>   08-09 00:15:09.782: E/AndroidRuntime(15550):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141) 08-09
>   00:15:09.782: E/AndroidRuntime(15550):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
>   08-09 00:15:09.782: E/AndroidRuntime(15550):  at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 08-09
>   00:15:09.782: E/AndroidRuntime(15550):    at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 08-09 00:15:09.782:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(15550):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103) 08-09
>   00:15:09.782: E/AndroidRuntime(15550):    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 08-09
>   00:15:09.782: E/AndroidRuntime(15550):    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 08-09 00:15:09.782:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(15550):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
>   08-09 00:15:09.782: E/AndroidRuntime(15550):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 08-09
>   00:15:09.782: E/AndroidRuntime(15550):    at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

if you need anything else please fell free to reply

Regards

Rapsong11

Answer (score 0):

`NDKmolActivity` tries to load library file called `libNdkmol.so`. Most likely, you forgot to add it to your project.

Comment: Sushil libNdkmol.so  is not in libs there is no libs folder any other suggestions? please let me know :)

Comment: Well, you have to get the lib somewhere. If you really need it. I guess, you found that project on github, eh? It doesn't have the lib for some reason. You can email the author of the github repo and ask them to share the lib with you.

Comment: it just says there's no nativeAdjustZoom in the lib class. Also, don't eraze the whole question like that, someone might bump into a similar problem, they should be able to find the whole case.

Answer (score 0):

Did you compile the library or took it from somewhere?